# разработка на Delphi на MacOS

Tags: delphi, macos, delphi-7

Какие есть программы для того, чтобы писать на *Delphi* на *MacOS*? Поиск в интернете дал ответ, что делфи не дружит с макинтошем, а на странице в википедии указана только *Windows*. Может все таки есть какие-то программы, кроме как установка параллельно *Windows*. Также можно найти сомнительные программы, поэтому хотел бы у вас спросить совета по выбору софта.

Comment: https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/mac-osx-development

Comment: @Igor вопрос про IDE под MacOS, а не компиляцию кода и деплой на macOS

Comment: Всегда можно поднять на маке виртуалку, на ней развернуть старый добрый Win3.1 и писать на черепашке Лого!!1раз

Comment: @Igor, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос во многом зависит от того, что конкретно Вы имели в виду.

### Если речь шла о разработке под MacOS

> Поиск в интернете дал ответ, что делфи не дружит с макинтошем

Ещё начиная с версии XE2 (2011 год) дружит. Другое дело более старые версии.

Если интересует именно разработка под Mac OS рекоменндую почитать книги Осипова по FireMonkey.

### Если Вас интересует установка Delphi на Mac OS

К сожалению, здесь ничего не выйдет. Delphi выпускается только для установки под Windows.

Поэтому если работаете под Mac OS, как основной системой, либо разворачивайте виртуалку с Windows и устанавливайте Delphi на неё, либо осваивайте кроссплатформенный Lazarus.

Есть ещё вариант перейти с Mac OS на Windows.

Как-то так...